# Error: Could not start the command

Tags: errors

I just installed MiKTeX 2.9 and Texmaker 4.3. The system is Windows 8.1. Following error appears whenever I run texmaker Quick Build:

> Error: Could not start the command. pdflatex -synctex=1
> -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Same question seems to be asked before but none of the recommended solutions works for me. I tried installing MiKTeX for all users and for one user. I also checked that file is saved as `filename.tex`. By the way, when I install MiKTeX 2.9 and Texmaker 4.3 on a Windows XP PC and apply exactly the same procedure, it works fine.

Comment: What happens if you try to run `pdflatex` from the command line?

Comment: While i run PDFLaTeX instead of Quick built, it says "Log File Not Found".

Comment: But what happens if you open a command prompt and enter 'pdflatex'?

Comment: If you mean Windows command prompt, it says "This is pdfTex, Version 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 <MiKTeX 2.9>"

Comment: This probably means that Texmaker is not configured correctly. Does section 1.2 of the [user manual](http://www.xm1math.net/texmaker/doc.html#SECTION02) help at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved by running TeXmaker as an administrator.